# stringstream conversion error

Tags: c++, stringstream

I had ever used the following code snippet in one class. Today, I copied it to another class. When compiling, I got the following errors. It is strange that such a thing has actually happened! Would you please tell what's the matter? Thank you.

I've just been using the following snippet code to do a test in a demo project. I ran like a charm!

```
int main()
{  
   char buffer[] = "I1 I2 V1 V2 I3 V3 I4 DO V4";

   std::stringstream s(buffer); 
   std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(s); 
   std::istream_iterator<std::string> end; 
   std::vector<std::string> IVector;
   std::vector<std::string> VVector;

   for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) 
   {     
       std::string sElem = *begin;

       switch((*begin)[0])
       {  
          case 'I':
            IVector.push_back( sElem);
            break;
          case 'V':
            VVector.push_back( sElem);
            break;
          default:
           ;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

void ClassifyChannel(char* szBuffer)
{   
    // Empty vectors
    m_svIRChannels.clear();
    m_svVISChannels.clear();

    std::stringstream s(szBuffer); 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> itBegin(s); 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> itEnd; 

    for (; itBegin != itEnd; ++itBegin) 
    {     
        std::string sElem = *itBegin;

        // Switch on first character
        switch ((*itBegin)[0])
        {  
           // Infrared channel, such as IR1, IR2, IR3 (WV), and IR4
           case 'I':
           case 'W':
              // Insert into IR channel vector here 
              m_svIRChannels.push_back(sElem);
              break;
           // Visible channels, such as VIS, and VIS1KM
           case 'V':
              // Insert into VIS channel vector here 
              m_svVISChannels.push_back(sElem);
              break;
        }
    } 
}
```

The error message is

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>f:\tips\tips\fy2hdf5dataiohandler.cpp(830) : error C2664: 'std::istream_iterator<_Ty>::istream_iterator(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::string,
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

Comment: This code seems to be ok. What stl do you use?

Comment: Your code as presented is missing required headers. With the headers added back, it compiles OK. Please post a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem. In general, code snippets cannot be evaluated for correctness.

Comment: @Mihran: He must be using the C++ Standard Library, due to the use of the `std` namespace. What implementation of the stdlib he's using is indeed up for debate!

Comment: I don't use the third-party STL library. I use VS 2008 built-in instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What compiler are you using? Your code snippet compiles fine with VC10 on my box. Did you forget to include all the proper header files? For this piece of code you need these 3 headers:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
```

Since VC10, `<iterator>` is not implicitly included by others. You need to include it yourself.

Comment: ..and this makes sense, because neither strings nor stringstreams use iterators inherently. You should always include the relevant standard headers for the functionality you wish to use, even if they happen to already be included by _other_ standard headers in your current stdlib implementation.

Comment: Mr. Tomalak Geret'kal, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My guess; you didn't explicitely do an

```
#include <string>
```

The IO stream headers just have a forward-declaration of `std::string`, but this is not sufficient in your case. Try explicitely including the `string` header to resolve this.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `std::stringstream` is being instantiated without error; i.e. it must be complete; This implies that `std::string` definition is also complete by that time because std::string is being returned/taken by value (e.g. `string str ( ) const;`).

Comment: @sehe: You can forward declare types if you return by value, too.

Comment: @Frerich: mmmm you got me thinking there. It appears you are right. I don't fully understand (surely this will create trouble with virtual destructors, to name just one thing that comes to mind?)

Comment: @Frerich: it is making sense now. The type needs to be complete at the time on invocation or body definition. The prototype definition actually doesn't really need to know anything - except that it wants to now the fully unambiguous type name so it can check (AOT) the ODR rule and parameter type compatibilty in invocations. To think I always took that way stricter

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sstream>
```

is required to include.

I tried in VS2017 and VS2019 and it is working by including this header.

Following is the sample code I tried.

```
int main()
{
    string line = "asasas asasas asasas asasas must try";
    stringstream check1(line);
}
```